# Generating unique values and filtering data object

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I'm trying to filter this data by type of ferment, then for each ferment type, combine the unique values of the use and year as arrays. For the "made" I want to add all the values up by year.

```
ferments = [
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2020", "made": 1}
]
```

I've tried many variations, and this is the closest I've gotten (without adding up the "made" values). This gives me an array of two objects, but I would like an object so that I can call it like so and get the relevant information for each key: `ferments[cabbage]`

```
const groupedByFerment = _(data)
.groupBy("ferment")
.map(d => ({
    // ferment: d[0].ferment,
    use: _(d).flatMap("use").uniq().value(),
    salt: _(d).flatMap("made").uniq().value(),
    year: _(d).flatMap("year").uniq().value(),
}))
.value()
```

Here's my desired output:

```
ferments = {
  cabbage: {
    use: [sauerkraut, pickled],
    year: [2018, 2019, 2020],
    made: [3, 3, 3],
   },
  beets: {
    use: [fermented, pickled],
    year: [2018, 2019, 2020],
    made: [5, 6, 5],
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single `reduce()` call, grouping by `ferment`, checking for `year` and incrementing `made` accordingly, and finally adding `use` if it doesn't already exist.

```js
const byFerment = ferments.reduce((a, o) => {
    let { use, year, made } = (a[o.ferment] ??= { use: [], year: [], made: [] });
    // check for year, if it exists access the same index in made and increment.
    let yearIndex = year.indexOf(o.year);
    if (yearIndex !== -1) {
      made[yearIndex] += o.made;
    } else {
      year.push(o.year);
      made.push(o.made);
    }
    // add use if it doesn't already exist.
    if (!use.includes(o.use)) use.push(o.use);
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log(byFerment);
```

```html
<script>
const ferments = [
  { "ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2018", "made": 2 },
  { "ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 1 },
  { "ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2019", "made": 2 },
  { "ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 1 },
  { "ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 3 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 3 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2018", "made": 2 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 4 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2019", "made": 2 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 4 },
  { "ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2020", "made": 1 }
];
</script>
```

**UPDATE: Implementation without [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)**

As noted in the comments the logical nullish assignment operator isn't yet fully supported. To implement the above without it is simply a matter of adding a line to retrieve/assign the property in the accumulator before proceeding.

This can be done either with an explicit check using `hasOwnProperty()`

```
a[o.ferment] = a.hasOwnProperty(o.ferment) ? a[o.ferment] : { use: [], year: [], made: [] };
```

or using short circuit assignment ideally with [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) otherwise `||`.

```
a[o.ferment] = a[o.ferment] || { use: [], year: [], made: [] };
```

```js
const byFerment = ferments.reduce((a, o) => {
//a[o.ferment] = a.hasOwnProperty(o.ferment) ? a[o.ferment] : { use: [], year: [], made: [] };
    //or
//a[o.ferment] = a[o.ferment] ?? { use: [], year: [], made: [] };
    // or
  a[o.ferment] = a[o.ferment] || { use: [], year: [], made: [] };
  
  let { use, year, made } = a[o.ferment];
  // check for year, if it exists access the same index in made and increment.
  let yearIndex = year.indexOf(o.year);
  if (yearIndex !== -1) {
    made[yearIndex] += o.made;
  } else {
    year.push(o.year);
    made.push(o.made);
  }
  // add use if it doesn't already exist.
  if (!use.includes(o.use)) use.push(o.use);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(byFerment);
```

```html
<script>
const ferments = [   {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2018", "made": 2 },   {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 1 },   {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2019", "made": 2 },   {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 1 },   {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 3 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 3 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2018", "made": 2 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 4 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2019", "made": 2 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 4 },   {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2020", "made": 1 } ];
</script>
```

---

A more robust structure would be to use an object to track years/made so as not to rely on parallel arrays. One could map this as two arrays using `Object.values()` for `made`, and `Object.keys()` for `year`.

```
{
  cabbage: {
    use: [ 'sauerkraut', 'pickled' ],
    years: { '2018': 3, '2019': 3, '2020': 3 }
  },
  beets: {
    use: [ 'pickled', 'fermented' ],
    years: { '2018': 5, '2019': 6, '2020': 5 }
  }
}
```

Which has the added benefit of simplifying the `reduce()`.

```
ferments.reduce((a, o) => {
  let { use, years } = (a[o.ferment] ??= { use: [], years: {} });
  if (!use.includes(o.use)) use.push(o.use);
  years[o.year] = (years[o.year] ?? 0) + o.made;
  return a;
}, {});
```

Comment: I can't find out what "??=" is as I've never seen it before. When I put this into VS code I got this error at the second line with '??=" "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."

Comment: It's Logical Nullish Assignment
https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup?match=logical-nullish-assignment

Comment: As noted above it's the [logical nullish assignment (??=) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), I've added an update that doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to group by the `ferment` using `.reduce`. Then, you can iterate over the resulting object using `.forOwn` to modify the year-made values and get unique `use` of each item:

```js
const ferments = [
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2020", "made": 1}
];

const grouped = _.reduce(ferments, (acc,item) => {
  const { ferment, use, year, made } = item;
  const prev = acc[ferment];
  acc[ferment] = prev
    ? { use:[...prev.use, use], year:[...prev.year, year], made:[...prev.made, made] }
    : { use:[use], year:[year], made:[made] };
  return acc;
}, {});

_.forOwn(grouped, (value,key) => {
  value.use = _.uniq(value.use);
  const { year:yearList, made:madeList } = value;
  const yearMadeMap = _.reduce(yearList, (acc,year,index) => {
     acc[year] = madeList[index] + (acc[year] || 0)
     return acc;
  }, {});
  value.year = _.keys(yearMadeMap);
  value.made = _.values(yearMadeMap);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ferments = [
  { ferment: "cabbage", use: "sauerkraut", year: "2018", made: 2 },
  { ferment: "cabbage", use: "pickled", year: "2018", made: 1 },
  { ferment: "cabbage", use: "sauerkraut", year: "2019", made: 2 },
  { ferment: "cabbage", use: "pickled", year: "2019", made: 1 },
  { ferment: "cabbage", use: "pickled", year: "2020", made: 3 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "pickled", year: "2018", made: 3 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "fermented", year: "2018", made: 2 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "pickled", year: "2019", made: 4 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "fermented", year: "2019", made: 2 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "pickled", year: "2020", made: 4 },
  { ferment: "beets", use: "fermented", year: "2020", made: 1 },
];

const data = {};

ferments.forEach((item) => {
  if (data[item.ferment] === undefined) {
    data[item.ferment] = { use: {}, year: {} };
  }
  data[item.ferment]["use"] = {
    ...data[item.ferment]["use"],
    [item.use]: true,
  };
  data[item.ferment]["year"][item.year] =
    data[item.ferment]["year"][item.year] === undefined ? item.made : data[item.ferment]["year"][item.year] + item.made;
});

const result = {};
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  result[key] = {
    use: Object.keys(data[key].use),
    year: Object.keys(data[key].year),
    made: Object.values(data[key].year),
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the array's items by the `ferment` value. Use `_.mapValues()` to iterate the group. Merge each groups, and add or concat the items according to the merged `key`. To concat use `_.union()` which concats and maintains uniqueness. Use `_.omit()` to remove the `ferment` key from the merged group object.

```js
const fn = arr => {
  // create groups by the ferment value
  const groups = _.groupBy(arr, 'ferment');
  
  return _.mapValues(groups, 
    group => _.omit( // remove ferment from the merged group
      // merge each group
      _.mergeWith({}, ...group, (o1, o2, key) => {
        // add made values
        if(key === 'made') return (o1 || 0) + o2;
        // concat use or year values while maintaining uniqueness
        if(key === 'use' || key === 'year') return _.union((o1 || []), [o2]);
    }), 'ferment'));
}

const ferments = [{"ferment":"cabbage","use":"sauerkraut","year":"2018","made":2},{"ferment":"cabbage","use":"pickled","year":"2018","made":1},{"ferment":"cabbage","use":"sauerkraut","year":"2019","made":2},{"ferment":"cabbage","use":"pickled","year":"2019","made":1},{"ferment":"cabbage","use":"pickled","year":"2020","made":3},{"ferment":"beets","use":"pickled","year":"2018","made":3},{"ferment":"beets","use":"fermented","year":"2018","made":2},{"ferment":"beets","use":"pickled","year":"2019","made":4},{"ferment":"beets","use":"fermented","year":"2019","made":2},{"ferment":"beets","use":"pickled","year":"2020","made":4},{"ferment":"beets","use":"fermented","year":"2020","made":1}];

const result = fn(ferments);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "sauerkraut", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 1},
  {"ferment": "cabbage", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2018", "made": 3},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2018", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2019", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2019", "made": 2},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "pickled", "year": "2020", "made": 4},
  {"ferment": "beets", "use": "fermented", "year": "2020", "made": 1}
];

const groupedByFerment = _(data)
  .groupBy("ferment")
  .mapValues(objectsWithTheSameFerment => ({
    use: _(objectsWithTheSameFerment)
      .flatMap("use")
      .uniq(),
    year: _(objectsWithTheSameFerment)
      .flatMap("year")
      .uniq(),
    made: _(objectsWithTheSameFerment)
      .groupBy("year")
      .map(objectsWithTheSameYear => _(objectsWithTheSameYear).sumBy("made")),
  }));
  
console.log(groupedByFerment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I'm looking for - the only thing that's missing are the country names. It's grouped by each of them, I don't want it to be an array, and I wanted each object to be set to its corresponding country.

Comment: I've updated the snippet (changed the first `map` to `mapValues`). Please, take a look